# Contact form only sending partial info

Tags: javascript, php

only some of my contact info is actually getting to my email.
Any reasons why?
Here's HTML:

```
 <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Full Name:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name='name'>
                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Phone Number:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name='phone'>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Email Address:</label>
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"  name='email'>
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Best way for us to reach back to you:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="reach"  name='reach'>
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Type of event: (ex. sports/wedding/business) </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="event"  name='event'>
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Date or Weekend Desired (ex. 4/16-4/25) </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date"  name='date'>
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Number of Attendees:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="attendees"  name='attendees'>
                    </div>
                </div>

                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Overnight Guests</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="overnight"  name='overnight'>
                    </div>

                </div>
                  <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Meals Included? (Yes/No/Maybe)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="meals" name='name'> 

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="control-group form-group">
                    <div class="controls">
                        <label>Additional Information:</label>
                        <textarea rows="10" cols="100" class="form-control" id="message" name='name' maxlength="39999" style="resize:none"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <!-- For success/fail messages -->
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
            </form>
```

My Javascript is:

```
$(function() {

    $("#contactForm input,#contactForm textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
        preventSubmit: true,
        submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
            // something to have when submit produces an error ?
            // Not decided if I need it yet
        },
        submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
            // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var name = $("input#reach").val();
            var name = $("input#date").val();
            var name = $("input#attendees").val();
            var name = $("input#overnight").val();
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "./bin/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    message: message
                },
                cache: false,
                success: function() {
                    // Success message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + " it seems that my mail server is not responding...</strong> Could you please email me directly to <a href='mailto:noah@webberd.com?Subject=Message_Me from myprogrammingblog.com;>noah@webberd.com</a> ? Sorry for the inconvenience!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});


/*When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes */
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

**and my PHP is here:**

```
$message = "Name: " . $_POST['name'];
$message .= "\r\nPhone " . $_POST['phone'];
$message .= "\r\nEmail: " . $_POST['email'];
$message .= "\r\nRequested Form of Contact: " . $_POST['reach'];
$message .= "\r\nEvent Type: " . $_POST['event'];
$message .= "\r\nRequested Dates: " . $_POST['date'];
$message .= "\r\nNumber of Attendees: " . $_POST['attendees'];
$message .= "\r\nOvernight Guests: " . $_POST['overnight'];
$message .= "\r\nMeals Included?: " . $_POST['meals'];
$message .= "\r\nAdditional Information: " . $_POST['message'];




$to = 'noahman2343@gmail.com'; 
$email_subject = "Wahnee Events Inquiry"; 
$email_body = $message;
$headers = "From: inquiry@wahneeevents.com\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";                                                                                                                                           
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

Much thanks -- strange issue -- searched all over here, but this is a strange issue.
Any one who helps - thanks so much!!

Comment: It might just be easier to serialize the form

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more data to:

```
data: {
    name: name,
    phone: phone,
    email: email,
    message: message
},
```

like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./bin/contact_me.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        name: name,
        phone: phone,
        email: email,
        message: message,
        reach: reach,
        date: date,
        attendees: attendees,
        overnight: overnight
    },
    ...
```

Also fetch values correctly here:

```
var name = $("#name").val(),
    phone = $("#phone").val(),
    email = $("#email").val(),
    message = $("#message").val(),
    reach = $("#reach").val(),
    date = $("#date").val(),
    attendees = $("#attendees").val(),
    overnight = $("#overnight").val();
```